# Unable to send variable value from JS to Java Class

Tags: javascript, servlets, httprequest, httpresponse

I am using Google Sign-in to and get the user email and token-id. I am capturing the values in the JavaScript function and this works correctly. Here's the code snippet used. I have a http servlet class that needs this data.

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark" onSubmit=></div>
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) { 

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token); 

    //send to backend
    postIt(id_token);
  };


  function postIt(id_token) { 
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
          } 
          xhttp.open("POST","index.jsp", true );
          xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          xhttp.send("id_token");   
  }

</script>
```

My Servlet looks like this:

```
   public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String id_token;
    String email; 

    id_token=request.getParameter("id_token"); 

    HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
    System.out.println("all is ok");
    try {
            System.out.print(id_token); 

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get uncaught TypeError in the browser console. I think the problem is in the postIt  function.
I am not able to understand how do I send the id_token value to the servlet. Can someone please correct my code?

Comment: I have got opening and matching closing braces for the postIt. When I run I see this error  'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look, there are three problems I see in your code:

1. There isn't any `#demo` element *(or you haven't provided it)*.
2. You haven't opened the `XMLHttpRequest` to your specific class.
3. You don't send the `id_token` to the server, just the parameter.

**Code:**

```
/* Open the request to the servlet. */
xhttp.open("POST", "TestServlet", true);

/* Send the token to the server mapped to the 'id_token' parameter. */
xhttp.send("id_token=" + id_token);
```

Comment: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = response; this isn't there...sorry.

Comment: I am still looking for an answer on how to send the value to my class.  I believe we need to do it  xhttp.open("POST", "https://httpbin.org/post", true); But question is how do I reference the class here?                                                                   var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText).form.id_token; Does this need form value because id_token is got after google signin and not the form value.

Comment: I have added a comment above the line you're referring to saying it's only used here in the snippet; in order to show you that the request works. The link I use is not the one you should send your request to. If the snippet confuses you, forget it. Re-read my answer to see where the problem lies in your code. In your request,  you only send the parameter to `Java`, without the token. Under **Code**, I show you the correct piece of code you have to use. You must concatenate the parameter name with an 'equal' sign and the token and send all of it. That's how an `XMLHttpRequest` works.

Comment: How does the code understand that it has to send the data to my class TestServlet ? Which line of the code says so?

Comment: It doesn't. `JavaScript` simply sends the `HMLHttpRequest` with the data server-side to the url given. What you do there doesn't concern the browser.

Comment: Do you know a way to send the data to class?

Comment: Simply use the name of the class as the url of the request. Check out the Code section in my answer; I've updated it to show you @smiley.